# How to add an area for a block of writing in python tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I have attached a screenshot of this person's gui and was wondering if anyone knows how he got the white box on the right.

In the video it does not show but is it a label or something? I am quite new and have never seen this before. I need to add my own data into it using variables but I don't know how to format the entire box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `Text` widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

t = Text(root)
t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also change the size by doing `t = Text(root, width=50, height=25)`. Height is actually the number of lines and width the number of characters on one line, not pixels. For more formatting options, go [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#reference).